# How to rotate a view without a jerk

Tags: android-animation

I want to rotate a view for infinite without any jerk, how can i achieve it.
 I try this and view is rotating fine but getting a jerk when one rotation completed.

xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <rotate
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
      android:fromDegrees="0"
      android:toDegrees="359"
      android:pivotX="50%"
      android:pivotY="50%"
      android:repeatCount="infinite"
      android:duration="500" />
```

in java code:

```
image.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,  R.anim.rotate_indefinitely));
```

Comment: Try to rotate to 360 degree

Comment: android:toDegrees="360" also not working

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think that the problem is with interpolator. Please try with

```
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
```